# Implementing lottery system in java fetching records from mysql in real time

Tags: java, mysql

I have been tasked to make a java lottery system that fetches cell phone numbers from the database and displays then in a textview. The system will work like this `1` A user clicks the start button, the system will start fetching the cell phone numbers randomly and very fast, about 10x in a second, then when they click on the stop button, the system stops fetching and the current displayed cell phone number wins,my solution was to use a timer that waits for `100 miliseconds`or if possible in realtime like

```
    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
      exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
       public void run() {
   // fetch from database
       }
     }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
```

But my problem is connecting to the database sometimes does result in overhead, how can i avoid this? I could fetch or the records in advance and store them in an arraylist but what if there is millions of records in the database again that will call for memory problems

Comment: Does`// fetch from database` look like 1) Make connection to DB 2) execute query to obtain one number 3) close connection?

Comment: yes it does, its a MSQL JAVA connection that connects and fetches records

Comment: instead you can, 1- fetch all numbers from db (if possible) in one request,  store in array or arraylist, then randomly display numbers from the fetched list, OR using old approach, but you can open the connection on start click, (open it once), only 1 connection, inside timer, each tick, just fetch a random record, and when stop clicked close the connection.

Comment: @Yazan I did not think of this, I will try to implement this and see its efficiency, arraylist is a bad idea, sometimes we can have millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

You need a solution that makes the connection once and then reuses it like this:

```
// when user presses START:
make DB connection
WHILE user has not pressed stop yet DO
    execute query to retrieve a number
    wait 100ms
ENDWHILE
close connection
```